# Editing in Google Docs returns "Oops. A server error occurred. Please press 'Reload' in your browser"

Tags: google-docs

When I work in Google Documents, I get the following error every time I edit something:

> Oops. A server error occurred. Please press 'Reload' in your browser

This happens every 30 seconds and is very unproductive.

Can it be fixed or do I have to return to the good old Microsoft Office?

Comment: I don't think any of the answers here are solutions. I've disabled all extensions and still have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this yesterday as well.  Not quite as frequently as you were, but occassionally.  I've also had major memory usage where I have to quit out of my browser (Firefox) and then continue by reloading the page, until memory used by Firefox grows again.

I'm a fan of Google Docs in concept, but the implementation of the spreadsheets at least leaves a lot to be desired in terms of reliability and performance.

Check your memory usage, and completely exit out of your browser and restart to see if that temporarily fixes the issue.

I'm also told that Chrome seems to be snappier with Google Docs.

Answer (score 1):

I started having the error asking me to reload Google Docs and Sheets every 30 seconds or so. It started to happen out of the blue. After pouring over information that goes as far back as 2011 when people were already posting the same issue, one of the fixes was to disable all extensions. I did and after enabling one by one, determined that it was the Google Offline Docs extension. The error message only came up while using Docs, Sheets, with that extension enabled.

Comment: I don't have that extension (double-checked), but still get this error message.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this and refreshed with the chrome network tab open and waited for the error to hit again.

I noticed a number of URLs like https://docs.google.com/static/spreadsheets2/client/js/1640903921-ritz_waffle_i18n_core.js showing `ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED` in the console and also "(from disk cache)" in the network activity panel.

So I cleared all my cached images and files and things seems to be stable with google docs again.

Answer (score 1):

If you see an error with "Google sheets" documents saying

> A loading error occurred. Please press 'Reload' in your browser

Try going to to Settings -> Clear browsing data -> Advanced -> "Hosted app data", and clear it.

Comment: This didn't work for me either. Had to log back in to all google services, but this error persists.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. 
I fixed mine by deleting/uninstalling some browser extensions.
One of your extensions could possibly be causing the problem.